# Spring Data / Hibernate save entity with Postgres using Insert on Conflict Update Some fields

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a domain object in Spring which I am saving using JpaRepository.save method and using Sequence generator from Postgres to generate id automatically.

```
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "device_metric_gen", sequenceName = "device_metric_seq")
public class DeviceMetric extends BaseTimeModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "device_metric_gen")
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
///// extra fields
```

My use-case requires to do an `upsert` instead of normal `save` operation (which I am aware will update if the id is present). I want to update an existing row if a combination of three columns (assume a composite unique) is present or else create a new row.
This is something similar to [this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/):

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES
   (
      'Microsoft',
      'hotline@microsoft.com'
   ) 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO
      UPDATE
     SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

One way of achieving the same in Spring-data that I can think of is:

1. Write a custom save operation in the service layer that
2. Does a get for the three-column and if a row is present
3. Set the same id in current object and do a repository.save
4. If no row present, do a normal repository.save

Problem with the above approach is that every `insert` now does a `select` and then `save` which makes two database calls whereas the same can be achieved by postgres `insert on conflict` feature with just one db call.
Any pointers on how to implement this in Spring Data?

One way is to write a native query `insert into values (all fields here)`. The object in question has around 25 fields so I am looking for an another better way to achieve the same.

Comment: All the options are in your question. Choose the one you dislike the least.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the response. You mean if I want to avoid two DB calls, I need to write an insert with all fields manually? No way spring can read it somehow if I pass the corresponding object?

Comment: maybe u can use @SQLInsert. INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES
   (
     ?,
      ?
   ) 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO
      UPDATE
     ...

Comment: @hosseinrasekhi I can but here I will need to write all the fields again, isn't it? I can make it in code like here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-insert but than too I'll have to add each field one by one.
I am looking for a way where I can use native query feature but pass the object and avoid setting multiple fields one by one.

Comment: @abstractKarshit Spring is irrelevant. JPA is what matters, and it doesn't do upserts. You can do it with native SQL. As I said, all the options are in your question. Choose the one you dislike the least.

Comment: @JBNizet Going with the first one for now. Thanks

Comment: Several times you mention that your object has many fields. Ask yourself how would you behave, if this object had only 4-5 fields? 

I believe, that writing all these fields in native query looks ugly at the beginning. But I also believe that it makes your code more clear, straightforward, and performant - exactly what you want to achieve, otherwise you would not care about an extra select query. And you can't achieve these things or be sure, that everything works in an optimal way when you use fancy ORM features.

Comment: Late to the party, but one more thought: Did you do any real life testing, whether you _really_ need the performance of avoiding one extra DB round trip? I wouldn't want to sacrifice easy, clean code for premature optimization and hacky workarounds.

Comment: @StefanHaberl The application in consideration was expected to have very high throughput and we were already using `INSERT ON CONFLICT` at other places. I wanted to find a cleaner way of doing this and if it was supported out of the box by JPA. I finally went ahead with Native SQL here but I don't think of it as a hack.

In hindsight, I agree with you that it would have been interesting to compare both the approaches by load test and then maybe prefer the more readable code if performance gain was not significant.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to shorten the native sql-query. But you could at least reduce the number of parameters in your method by using SpEL in your query. E.g.


`@Query("INSERT INTO t(a, b, c) VALUES (:#{#entity.a}, :#{#entity.b}, :#{#entity.c}) ON CONFLICT ... RETURNING *")`

Answer (score 1):

As @JBNizet mentioned, you answered your own question by suggesting reading for the data and then updating if found and inserting otherwise. Here's how you could do it using spring data and `Optional`.

Define a `findByField1AndField2AndField3` method on your `DeviceMetricRepository`.

```
public interface DeviceMetricRepository extends JpaRepository<DeviceMetric, UUID> {
    Optional<DeviceMetric> findByField1AndField2AndField3(String field1, String field2, String field3);
}
```

Use the repository in a service method.

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class DeviceMetricService {
        private final DeviceMetricRepository repo;
        DeviceMetric save(String email, String phoneNumber) {
            DeviceMetric deviceMetric = repo.findByField1AndField2AndField3("field1", "field", "field3")
                .orElse(new DeviceMetric()); // create new object in a way that makes sense for you
            deviceMetric.setEmail(email);
           deviceMetric.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        return repo.save(deviceMetric);
    }
}
```

**A word of advice on observability**:
You mentioned that this is a high throughput use case in your system. Regardless of the approach taken, consider instrumenting timers around this save. This way you can measure the initial performance against any tunings you make in an objective way. Look at this an experiment and be prepared to pivot to other solutions as needed. If you are always reading these three columns together, ensure they are indexed. With these things in place, you may find that reading to determine update/insert is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a named query to fetch a row based on your candidate keys. If a row is present, update it, otherwise create a new row. Both of these operations can be done using the save method.

```
@NamedQuery(name="getCustomerByNameAndEmail", query="select a from Customers a where a.name = :name and a.email = :email");
```

You can also use the @UniqueColumns() annotation on the entity to make sure that these columns always maintain uniqueness when grouped together.

```
Optional<Customers> customer = customerRepo.getCustomersByNameAndEmail(name, email);
```

Implement the above method in your repository. All it will do it call the query and pass the name and email as parameters. Make sure to return an Optional.empty() if there is no row present.

```
Customers c;
if (customer.isPresent()) {
    c = customer.get();
    c.setEmail("newemail@gmail.com");
    c.setPhone("9420420420");
    customerRepo.save(c);
} else {
    c = new Customer(0, "name", "email", "5451515478");
    customerRepo.save(c);
}
```

Pass the ID as 0 and JPA will insert a new row with the ID generated according to the sequence generator.

Although I never recommend using a number as an ID, if possible use a randomly generated UUID for the primary key, it will qurantee uniqueness and avoid any unexpected behaviour that may come with sequence generators.